# Cant select data from two tables using mysql

Tags: mysql

I  can't select data from two tables using mysql. I have 2 tables sales and receipt.

The sale table contains

```
id       date             total
26       2014-07-16       5000
27       2014-07-16       7000
```

Receipt table structure

```
id      date                nettotal
18      2014-07-16          2000
19      2014-07-16          1000
```

I want to get result like as

```
date             total      nettotal 
2014-07-16       5000
2014-07-16       7000
2014-07-16                  2000
2014-07-16                  1000
```

How get the result ?
Anybody help  me?

Comment: Please include the mysql code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you union them together?

```
SELECT date, total, null as nettotal
FROM sales
UNION
SELECT date, null, nettotal
FROM receipt
```